# AWS IAM Groups naming strategy

Tags: amazon-web-services, naming-conventions, amazon-iam, naming, usergroups

I'm new to AWS IAM and I was wondering if there is a best practice for naming groups for development and deployment. I search on the internet for some article that recommends a best practices but couldn't find one. One naming strategy and example names are:

> project_name.role

For example:

> my_new_project.deployer <--  for users that want to deploy
>
> my_new_project.app <--  it will contain policies regarded to the app (if it has to communicate with other services, etc)

Any other suggestion for naming groups?

Answer (score 9):

AWS provides a [tagging best practices](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-tagging-best-practices.pdf) guide which discusses the naming for tags and resources.

For resources, it recommends a dot notation:

1. account-name prefix: for example, production, development
2. resource-name: free-form field for the logical name of the resource
3. type suffix: for example, subnet, sg, role, policy, kms-key

And gives the following examples:

1. prod.ec2-s3-access.role
2. dr.ec2-s3-access.role